# Why is my recaptcha response unsuccessful?

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

I have been looking for what I might be doing wrong and for solutions all over but none seem to rectify my problem. I have a form with a recaptcha, it is pretty simple. But my recaptcha validation fails every time and echo's "Not successful" when it should be successful. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
<?php
require_once('src/autoload.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/ReCaptcha.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/RequestParameters.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/Response.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Post.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Socket.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/SocketPost.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/Curl.php');
require_once('src/ReCaptcha/RequestMethod/CurlPost.php');

$gRecaptchaResponse = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$remoteIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$SITEKEY = 'XXXX';
$secret = 'XXXX';

$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    echo "not success";
    echo $errors;
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried without sending the user's IP. I have had issues before where it didn't work for some reason when doing this and after all, it's only optional.

Comment: @ThomasSmyth Doesnt work:(

Comment: How are you calling this file? Is it when you submit a form or is it an AJAX call from a button on the same page as the form?

Comment: Im calling this file when submitting a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//reCaptcha
$StrUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$StrSecretKey = "XXXXXX";

$data = array('secret' => $StrSecretKey, 'response' => $_POST['Response']);

$ch = curl_init($StrUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$Response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$Robot = json_decode($Response);

$data = 0;

if(isset($Robot->success) AND $Robot->success==true){
   //CODE
}
```

Try this. It was originally designed for an AJAX call, however if you change the $_POST['Response'] to the name of the response variable then it should work, hopefully.

Comment: No problem. Pleasure to be of assistance.